# Is it possible to track in app purchase in android / ios without database react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-iap

I have in app purchase in android and ios. What i want is I want to validate that purchases in multiple devices without forcing user to register/login. Because My ios app is rejected and here is they said..

*Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal information to purchase non account-based in-app purchase products, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, please do not force users to log in to make purchase.

Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app content and features that are not associated specifically to the user.

Next Steps

User registration that requires the sharing of personal information must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality.

To resolve this issue, please make it clear to the user that registering will enable them to access the content from any of their iOS devices and provide them a way to register at any time, if they wish to later extend access to additional iOS devices.

Please note that although guideline 3.1.2 of the App Store Review Guidelines requires an app to make subscription content available to all the iOS devices owned by a single user, it is not appropriate to force user registration to meet this requirement; such user registration must be made optional.*

So, now we want to change flow of our app. how can i track purchase details of purchase using goole id(for android) apple id(for ios).
Thank you.

Comment: afaik you need in-app registration/login for fetching data about purchases history on Android...

Comment: I have did that but apple rejected my app and says that don't force user to login/register to purchase product

Comment: Are you using auto renewing subscriptions or non auto renewing subscriptions. If the former then you can simply provide a "restore purchases" button and that will enable a user to enable their subscription on another device. If it is a non-renewing subscription then there is no way they can access their sub on another device without creating an account but you can't make this mandatory. You can explain the benefits of creating an optional account (such as the ability to access their sub on another device)

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, but i am using non-renewable purchases. So, according to you If i want to convince apple team to accept my app then i need to clarify benefits of login/register to continue then apple will accept my app, right?

Comment: As Apple have explained, the account creation cannot be mandatory. Even if you explain the benefits of registering and/or the drawback of not registering, you cannot require the user to do so.

Comment: Then what should i do to make my app accepted ? Any suggestion?

Comment: Make it so that the user doesn't not have to create an account. The account creation must be optional.